# render a django template from database html contents

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have raw html saved in my database contents. I want that to render that content, following is the way, I try -

```
    from django.template import Context, Template
    l = MyModel.objects.get(slug=current_slug)
    tpl = Template(escape(l.content_text))
    return HttpResponse(tpl.render(Context({})))
```

This renders html as string, and in the template I see `<html>.....</html>` instead of the rendered content.

Let me know, how this can be fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `mark_safe()` not `escape()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `escape`:

```
tpl = Template(l.content_text)
```